# Language pack security updates SharePoint 2019 language dependent which language to install?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, language

We are running SharePoint 2019 English version, with a Swedish language pack also installed on top (we show all our sites in Swedish).

Now for the language pack security updates for Aug 2021 KB5002000 and KB5002001 KB5002000 was installed automatically from windows update but I wonder in what language should I install KB5002001?

Should it be English because that is the default installation of SharePoint or is it Swedish because we have a Swedish language pack  or is it both?

Appreciate an answer as I am new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, you need to install Language Pack twice, install the Language Pack for English and Swedish respectively.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Install KB5002000
2. Install KB5002001 Swedish Language
3. Run Config Manager step 3

Comment: So even though the Sharepoint installation is in english I do not need to install KB5002001 in english also? Just swedish that is my extra installed language pack? The answer above tells me I need to install both? Or is there any harm in installing both?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

1. KB5002000 is the **Language independent** CU and security update both
2. KB5002001 is the **language dependent** CU

You need to install both. Please note it does not matter what language you choose from the drop down to download for language dependent CU. All the files for Language dependent are same. So if you choose English or Swedish it does not matter.

So to keep it simple. Download both the CU and keep the Language as English in the drop down and install it and then run the psconfig wizard

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103369

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103375